# Multiple instances of CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, cllocationmanager

In my App somehow multiple instances of `CLLocationManager` are running.

When I print the output to console, I get following result:

```
<+XX.XXXXXX,+XX.XXXXXX> +/- 5.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 3/9/17, 1:05:11 PM India Standard Time
<+XX.XXXXXX,+XX.XXXXXX> +/- 5.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 3/9/17, 1:01:18 PM India Standard Time
```

**Note the timestamps, this statements are printed in same order.**

In one previous view I use `CLLocationManager` to get user location, then stop it, & in here user movement is monitored. But somehow that previous `CLLocationManager` instance is still in memory & when I do `startUpdatingLocation()` both current one & previous one get active.

What might be the issue? How the prevent `CLLocationManager` instance sticking in memory?

Comment: You may create a `Singleton` for `CLLocationManager`.

Comment: @chengsam thanks, I was thinking same, but is there any way to clear that instance from memory & start clean?

Comment: You need to show some code. How and wen are you allocating the location manager? How is the output you show generatted? Method in the delegate?

Comment: @demonofthemist just use the Memory Graph in Xcode and you will find why is that.

Answer (score -1):

For these I issues I would suggest to use `CLLocationManager` based on a [Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern.

You can find this already done, by checking [CLLocationManager-Singleton-in-Swift](https://github.com/igroomgrim/CLLocationManager-Singleton-in-Swift).

Following this approach should let you to guarantee that the same  `CLLocationManager` instance will handle both operations.

> How the prevent CLLocationManager instance sticking in memory?

You might want to declare it as *optional* variable:

```
var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
```

When you need to use it:

```
// set it up
locationManager = CLLocationManager()
locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
locationManager?.delegate = self
```

And when you need to remove it:

```
// removing it
locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
locationManager?.delegate = nil
locationManager = nil
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Hi, I created a singleton as you suggested but still I can see those two calls :( Maybe some other function is calling it repeatedly but I can't find any & can you explain the way timestamp is printing?

Comment: Making it optional won't help if there is an old instance hanging around.